# @inject HttpClient httpClient vs builder.Services.AddHttpClient in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Is there any reason why we don't have `GetFromJsonAsync` method available when we use named HttpClients. I had to Install NewtonSoftJson to deserialize the response when I switched to Named HttpClients.

**Injecting in Razor Component**

```
@inject HttpClient httpClient

@code{

    public async Task GetProfileAsync()
    {
        User user = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<User>("user/getprofile/10");
    }
}
```

**Injecting in a service/class**

```
        public ProfileViewModel(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task GetProfileAsync()
        {
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "user/getprofile/10");
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            
            User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(responseBody);
        }
```

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Comment: Ok let me chnage that.

Answer (score 3):

They are extension methods. Just add

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;
```

and when you do need to (de)serialize manually, prefer `System.Text.Json`. It is the default and preferred API now.

There are still some use-cases for NewtonSoft but they are disappearing fast.

Comment: Check your _Imports.razor file.

Comment: I use Newtonsoft, S.T.Json just doesn't work well enough.

Comment: I didn't compare much myself but SysText is supposed to be faster. And the future. But there are legacy Web API's that will need tweaking. Usually about camelCasing on/off.

Answer (score 1):

add `using System.Net.Http.Json` for using extension methods

Namespaces :

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
```

Methods :

```
public ProfileViewModel(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}

public async Task GetProfileAsync()
{
    User user = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<User>("user/getprofile/10");    
}

public async Task UpdateProfile()
{        
    await _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync("user/updateprofile/10", user);
}
```